# How to give selected options tag - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a simple select tag which fetches data from database.

```
<select *ngIf="projects.length" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject">
<option *ngFor="let projectTypeModel of projects" [ngValue]="projectTypeModel">{{projectTypeModel.ProjectName}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to show text "Select Project Type" to be selected as default.
The code I have added is:

```
<select *ngIf="projects.length" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject">
 <option [selected]="true">Select Project Type</option>
 <option *ngFor="let projectTypeModel of projects" [ngValue]="projectTypeModel">{{projectTypeModel.ProjectName}}</option>
 </select>
```

But this doesnot work. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <select *ngIf="projects.length" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject">
     <option [selected]="true" value="" disabled>Select Project Type</option>
     <option *ngFor="let opt of projects" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.ProjectName}}</option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedProject: string = ''; // string or number

  projects = [
    { ProjectName: "option 1", value: 'op1' },
    { ProjectName: "option 2", value: 'op2' },
    { ProjectName: "option 3", value: 'op3' },
  ];
}
```

Online demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/rNHjQs?p=preview

Comment: This work well in UI. However, when I select this option again I get Bad request as I am calling method to populate Projects based on this values

Comment: btw, this is not related with first question

Comment: To  make both UI and code work, I just added a disabled tag in option  <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Project Type</option>

Comment: you mean, first option. i think so, because the first option do not contain `value` -> request won't match API requirement.

Comment: I just want to mention something: `[selected]="true"` does absolutely nothing here.